# Java working with superclasses, but I do not get the output I expect

Tags: java, inheritance

Hi I have written this program that Implements a superclass Employee that has the following fields and methods.

Fields:

```
String firstName
String lastName
int employeeID
double salary
```

Methods:

```
Constructor():  initialize balance field to null and zero.
Setters and getters for firstName, lastName, and employeeID
EmployeeSummary() – prints all account attributes
Part 2: Implement a Manager class that inherits from the Employee class.
```

Has a department attribute
Methods:

```
EmployeeSummary() – prints all superclass and subclass attributes
```

The problem is I expected to see:

> Employee Name: Charles Dickens Employee Id : 34599 salary: 6500.0
>   Department : Accounts

as the output but I get nothing....
Any help is greatly appreciated.
here is the code:

```
package week1john_huber;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Employee {
    //attributes of Employee class
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int employeeID;
    private double salary;


    public Employee() { //default constructor
        firstName = null;
        lastName = null;
        employeeID = 0;
        salary = 0.0;

    }

    public void setFirstName(String fname) { //set and get methods for all attributes
        firstName = fname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lname) {
        lastName = lname;
    }

    public double getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(int empId) {
        employeeID = empId;

    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double s) {
        salary = s;
    }

    public void EmployeeSummary() { //display all attributes of Employee
        System.out.println("Employee Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + " Employee Id :" + employeeID + " salary: " + salary);
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
    private String department;


    public Manager() { //default constructor
        super();                           //calling superor base class default constructor
        department = null;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String dept) { //set and get methods for department
        department = dept;
    }

    public void EmployeeSummary() {
        super.EmployeeSummary();     //calling super class method with same name
        System.out.println("Department : " + department);
    }
}

class TestEmployee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Manager mgr = new Manager();
        mgr.setFirstName("Charles");        //all set methods of super class are available to derived class
        mgr.setLastName("Dickens");
        mgr.setEmployeeID(34599);
        mgr.setSalary(6500);
        mgr.setDepartment("Accounts");
        mgr.EmployeeSummary();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running your code? also the class TesyEmployee must be public

Comment: I have run your code and it returns the exact data you say it should:
Employee Name: Charles Dickens Employee Id : 34599 salary: 6500.0
Department : Accounts

Comment: please check your execution environment (i.e. the IDE) as maybe it is sending stdout to a place were you don't expect

Comment: weird it wont run for me, no errors just shows nothing in the output.

Comment: Do you have everything you posted in the same file?

Comment: yes all in the same file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe the problem is the fact that you have the whole thing in a single file.

Try moving the `TestEmployee` class to its own file and rename the class to

```
public class TestEmployee
```

It should work that way.